# how to write a variable into class

Tags: python

I am new to Python classes, so my question is:
how can I write this:

```
genome = {'speed': 0.03999485472564734, 
                        'max_speed': 0.26692713899472725,
                        'max_rotation': 0.04739626947680464, 
                        'track_time': 36}
```

into a class, so that it can be accessed like this:

```
class Genome:
   ... the genome dict here as variables ...

class Species():
  def __init__(self):
    ....

s = Species()
print(s.genome.speed)# should give me the speed
```

maybe my approach is not the proper way. The idea is to have a Class Species, which can reproduce itself and then overgive all values from genome to the child, but not everything else?
thanks for your help

I tried to overgive genome simply as a dictionary, it works but it is annoying to write all the time like:
self.genome["speed"] etc... I want to get rid of the ["..."] syntax.
Or: how to do something in a smart way?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html would be a good starting point

Answer (score 2):

This is what a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) is for:

```py
@dataclass
class Genome():
    speed: float
    max_speed: float
    max_rotation: float
    track_time: int
```

Instead of initilizing it like a dictionary:
`self.genome = {"speed": ..., ...}`

Do something like: `self.genome = Genome(speed=..., max_speed=..., max_rotation=..., track_time=...)`

Side note: You do not need the `speed=` or `track_time=` parts beforehand if you write these in order.

In order to get something like what you pointed out in the comment, you can use `vars` to get each item in the class and `getattr(genome, name)` to get the attribute like:

```py
for key in vars(genome):
    item = getattr(genome, key)
```

Comment: ok. thanks-- but the problem is, this is just a sample of a dict with dozens of items.. so i need to rewrite it? i am trying something like: for key,value in genome.items():
            
            exec("self." + str(key) + " = " + str(value)) doesnt work so far-- i mean to turn a dict into a class without writing it . is it even possible?

Comment: I updated to include something that you may have been looking for.

Comment: "self.genome = Genome(speed=..., max_speed=..., max_rotation=..., track_time=...)"---> i think this could solve the problem !

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
genome = {'speed': 0.03999485472564734, 
          'max_speed': 0.26692713899472725,
          'max_rotation': 0.04739626947680464, 
          'track_time': 36}

class Genome:
    def __init__(self, genome):
        for k, v in genome.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)


class Species:
    def __init__(self):
        self.genome = Genome(genome)
```

For example:

```
x = Species()
print(x.genome.speed)
```

gives:

```
0.03999485472564734
```